# Resize Ubuntu boot partition with swap partition adjacent to it

Tags: partition, gparted

I'm trying to resize a /boot partition use gparted from an Ubuntu LiveCD. The problem is that I have a linux swap and extended partition right adjacent to the /boot partition. The unallocated space is after these partitions. The screenshot attached depicts better what I'm trying to say.

By the looks of it, I can't seem to rezise the /boot partition since there are those 2 small partitions in the middle. Can I resize my /boot partition to include the unallocated space in it?

P.S. I'm not extremely knowledgeable about partitions so sry if it's a newbie question. I have working knowledge of Linux though.

Thanks,

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can remove a swap partition, move it to the end of free place and then resize partition sda1 to fill free space on the disk...

Then you will have to use a `resize2fs` utility to resize filesystem to the whole partition.

Comment: Ok managed. Didn't understand the scope of resize2fs though. Why is it used?

Comment: Resizing the partition only makes the block device bigger. `resize2fs` makes the changes needed to the internal data of the filesystem so that the new space that has magically appeared can be used.